# Chrome downloads image even if it's in the cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm using jQuery `$("#my-image").attr("src", "/img/...")` (and also `.css("background-image", "url()")`to show some images. I now discovered that Chrome redownloads the file completely every time the page is loaded or even the js is executed. This shouldn't happen. Why is the cache not used? In Firefox it works like it should. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your console open and do you have the checkbox "*Disable cache (while DevTools is open)*" checked?

Comment: no, that is unchecked.